# Please help me with installing Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, downloads

I just downloaded Ubuntu Bionic Beaver desktop, but it does not run. All I get is a window with a bunch of files in it. Does anyone know how to actually install Ubuntu from the download? Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: there is the main iso and some signatures for verification

Answer (score 1):

There’s [a pretty good walk-through](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) on the downloads page. This will show you how to burn a CD or prep a USB stick and go through the install process. Welcome to Ubuntu